# Highcharts -Highmaps making map curved(geojson QGIS)

Tags: highcharts, geojson, qgis, highmaps

I am trying to draw US outline in highmaps using geojson. My map is straight.

However I would like to make it curved like below link.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/us-counties/
Here is image of curved map.
[image]

Ignore below geojson as I can't paste all here.

Here is link to paste of geojson : https://paste.fedoraproject.org/413593/. Geojson was generated using QGIS. Below is map generated by this geojson

[image: Map generated by geojson]

Here is quick link to test geojson. 
http://jsfiddle.net/o7u6j6ck/

```
> > {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features":
> > [{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Mult
> 
> iPolygon","coordinates":
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of projections. Geojson can only deal with [WGS84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System), which is a subset of the [Mercator Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection).

The curved map you've shown is drawn using the [Albers-USA projection](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5545680).

You can use D3.js to play with [different map projections](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#projections). IIRC D3 can read from valid GeoJSON/TopoJSON and reproject it using the projection of your choice.

Comment: I am naive in the matter of projections. How could i change projection to Albers-USA projection.

Comment: Also , at the moment I am limited to using highchats / highmaps

Comment: What if you use the json source that's shown in highmaps examples? Perhaps it isn't valid geojson but instead a reprojected yet topologically closed collection

Comment: I have to add MSA/CBSAs in the map, which is not possible with re-projected json from Highcharts as MSA shapefile is same as this one(i.e. flat one)

Comment: @Don I had the same issue when trying to work with a map using MSAs. You need to have an SVG that contains the MSA boundaries **and** has the projection you want. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find one in places like the U.S. Census Bureau. You may need to find a mapping resource or program and roll your own. There's another Stack Exchange community called "Geographic Information Systems" that may be helpful for you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Don Hi...want to know if you had any luck with Highmaps for a US map with CSA and MSA with Albers-USA projection?...I have a similar requirement and have not been able to find the approach for the same. I had a topojson file for CSA, which I converted to geojson using topojson-client library, but the projection isn't coming nice for the same after the conversion. Any leads would be appreciated.